# Tikz package conflicts with other pictures?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, errors

I have normal pictures included in my LaTeX document, once I add the package `\usepackage{tikz,tikzscale,pgfplots}`, I start getting my original file name with a bunch of different file formats printed in my pdf. I used to have a `tikzpicture` included like:

```
\newlength\fheight
\newlength\fwidth
\setlength\fheight{5cm}
\setlength\fwidth{5cm}
\includegraphics[width=1\fwidth]{ NAME.tikz}
```

in my figure environment.

But it still screw up my entire document without a `tikzpicture` included. To be clear, the original picture in this case was from a pdf. I'm adding `tikz` figures converted from Matlab. Google didn't help so far..

Edit: I wasn't very clear it seems. I can include the NAME.tikz file. The other figures get messed up (png, jpeg, pdf). Not all of them for some reason to. I thought it might have had something to do with floats since I use

```
\begin{figure}[H]
```

but removing the [H] didn't help.
[image: Example of problem]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `.tikz` is not type of graphic. if you like to include tikz code, than you should say `\input{<tikzcodename>.tex}` where `tikzcodename` is name of file in which is code of your image.

Comment: And should Matlab produce output with a tikz extension (for whatever reason), then do `\input{NAME.tikz}`.

Comment: @Zarko The OP is loading `tikzscale`. Doesn't it allow this syntax?

Comment: @JPI The OP is loading `tikzscale`. `\includegraphics{<filename>}` or `\includegraphics{<filename>.tikz}` should work fine. (The former is OK only if the extension is `tikz`.) `\input` as you've got it will not scale the picture as the OP wants.

Comment: @cfr, i wasn't enough careful reading OP post. this for sure be far more easy, if answer had *mwe*. and frankly said i'm not familiar with *matlab* exported images.

Comment: We need an example which reproduces the problem in order to help you. There's not enough information right now - what you've shown won't produce the output you've pictured.

Comment: Thanks for the comments nonetheless, I'm working with a tight deadline right now so was hoping for a quick solution. I'm just going to evade including the tikz package for now and will update if I figure it out later